# Combining When clause with tail: _* on Spark Scala Dataframe

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Given this statement 1:

```
val aggDF3 = aggDF2.select(cols.map { col => ( when(size(aggDF2(col)) === 0,lit(null))
                   .otherwise(aggDF2(col))).as(s"$col") }: _*)
```

Given this statement 2:

```
aggDF.select(colsToSelect.head, colsToSelect.tail: _*).show()
```

Can I combine the **when logic...** on statement 1 with the **colsToSelect.tail: _*** in a single statement, so that the first field is just selected, and the logic only applies to tail scope of dataframe colums? Tried various aspects, but on thin ice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
val aggDF : DataFrame = ???
val colsToSelect : Seq[String] = ???

aggDF
  .select((col(colsToSelect.head) +: colsToSelect.tail.map
      (col => when(size(aggDF(col)) === 0,lit(null))
  .otherwise(aggDF(col)).as(s"$col"))):_*)
  .show()
```

remember that `select` is overloaded and works differently with `String` and `Column`: With `cols : Seq[String]`, you need `select(cols.head,cols.tail:_*)`, with `cols : Seq[Column]` you need `select(cols:_*)`. The solution above uses the second variant.

Comment: That + I was missing. Great stuff, now time for duck!